# motorola Atrix RAM usage

Tags: android, ram, motorola

I have a motorola atrix phone. I used the stock Task Manager but it doesnt reveal how much RAM is used or available. Does anyone know how to check RAM usage on this phone

Regards

Comment: Not really a programming question, you should try asking this on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should download the Advanced task Killer for Android app from Android market.
http://goo.gl/0BvU8

Comment: I did that and also later i realized the stock task manager does show in one of the tabs the RAM usage. Thanks for the help